# Best way of using an UART with an visual studio code for wpf and connected to an arduino?

Tags: c#, arduino, uart

Need a robust way of applying serial communication between WPF and an MCU.

Had tried read existing method for receiving serial data but it's not workng perfectly all time and I am able to send serial data from wpf to mcu sucessfully everytime.

I am using this code for receiving an serial data.

```
            data_in = string.Empty;
            data_in = serialPort1.ReadExisting();
            //Console.WriteLine(data_in);
            this.Invoke(new EventHandler(showData));
```

basically I am trying to have a handshake kind of thing so on comport open in windows form I send an "AT" on serial port and it is received perfectly on my esp32 and I compare "AT" on esp32 a reply back "OK".
in esp32 for data sending, I used this syntax

```
Serial.print("OK");
```

and my problem is that when I compare it compares ok but sometimes it does not.

```
if(data_in=="OK")
{

}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show what you've come up with so far, and explain why it isn't working the way you expected it to.

Comment: The world is synchronous. You’re assuming that you got all the data at the point where you expect it. It’s not always the case, and the reception of data may be done in chunks that are much smaller than you expect. There’s no guarantee that you’ll read the entire reply in one go. You may also read way more than that reply. So the comparison has usually a higher chance of failure than success. Your communications routine should be rewritten to be either an explicit state machine that reacts to communications events, or as an async function with support for timeouts.

Comment: @ReinstateMonica As per I have searched the function 
`serialPort1.ReadExisting();` 
continues to read all existing data packets from com port until set timeout ocures.